# usb / card swipe over RDP

Tags: windows, windows-7

Can a magtek Swipe Card machine (USB connection) be used in a RDP session? i.e. the swipe card machine is plugged into a laptop...the laptop connects remotely via vpn and then RDP to a workstation...the laptop accesses a software package on the workstation which requires the swiping of a card for information...the card is swiped remotely, but the workstation software reads the swipe as though the device was plugged directly into the local usb port.

Presently when the card is swiped the software doesn't consistently read the information correctly. However when you do test swipe into notepad the card info is there.

Comment: `Can a magtek Swipe Card machine (USB connection) be used in a RDP session?` - `Presently when the card is swiped the software doesn't consistently read the information correctly. However when you do test swipe into notepad the card info is there.` - Haven't you answered your own question? You CAN swipe the card but it isn't read consistently. So the question isn't `can the swipe reader be used?` but is rather `how can the swipe reader be used reliably?`. Have you talked to the vendor that you purchased the swipe reader from?

Comment: Nope...There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the actual swipe card machine..we've tested 3 of them and its the same with each. It just doesn't work consistently. The 3rd party vendor has no clue why it doesn't work. They've never had anyone try this before.

Comment: To clarify: If you swipe to notepad in the RDP session it works correctly but if you swipe to the application it's inconsistent?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: What's being scanned on the card? Presumably a bar code? If so, what is the symbology? Codabar? Code 25? Etc. What happens if you scan a different type of bar code or card?

Comment: It's a health insurance card with a magnetic strip....I'm not sure of the symbology (not an IT person)...when we swipe a credit card, with a similar type strip in notepad the person's name comes up....when we use a barcode scanner and scan a barcode of a product in the software the correct item description comes up

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, or at least is possible, depending on the device.  In Windows, you'd be looking at the "Local devices and resources" RDP option, as below, and either the `Ports` or  `Other supported Plug and Play (PnP) devices` boxes, as below.

[image]

Of course, there is that caveat in there of "supported" devices.  Based on your statement of inconsistency on the part of the application, I would guess that either the device or the application don't support doing this over an RDP session, or don't support it well.  In either case, it's something you'll have to address with the 3rd party vendor, though the typical troubleshooting activities like modifying encryption and connection quality options for the RDP session, updating software and drivers, and so on sound like they'd be worth looking into as well.

Comment: @user217688  Then you are probably out of luck.  Troubleshoot it, push your vendors to fix it, find a new device/application to read magnetic card swipes, or eliminate the *reading-cards-over-RDP* part of your process.